Multiple if conditions in shell script
I am using shell script and trying below where I searching for two strings in a file if they are passing then I need to print "PASS" as shown in below code but getting issue when executing below code.
#!/bin/bash
if [[ (grep -q "Build of target from_sms.compfiles.xf : PASS" failed.log) && (grep -q "All tests fine" test.log) ]]; then
  echo "PASS"
fi


drop parenthesis! grep -q "Build of target from_sms.compfiles.xf : PASS" failed.log && grep -q "All tests fine" test.log && echo "PASS" could be enough

Stop thinking of "conditions". The syntax of the shell is not if condition, it is if command.  eg if grep ... && grep ....

Other than using [[ instead of [, this is asked and answered in Checking the success of a command in a bash if [ .. ] statement

Your question is uncler. You write in the title multiple if condition, but your if has as argument only a signe [[ ... ]] statiement, and even this does not make sense. For instance you never execute any grep command in your code (as you can see, when you run your script with set -x turned on.

You dont need to put square brackets around grep command as it already returns "0" or "1" which is what exactly if needs.
here for example:
$ grep -q PASS /tmp/file
$ echo $?
0 
$ grep -q FOO /tmp/file
$ echo $?
1

So your code could be:
$ if grep -q PASS /tmp/file && grep -q "All tests fine"  /tmp/file2 ; then echo "PASS"; fi
PASS
$ cat /tmp/file
PASS
$ cat /tmp/file2
All tests fine

let me know if this is not what you are looking for.
